# Classify $I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{dx}{\sin(x)^a\cos(x)^b}$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Classify  $I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{dx}{\sin(x)^a\cos(x)^b}$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$.

I'm really lost, this excercise is so different from the others and I can't find any similar questions online,  <s>the integral seems to converge if -1< a+b <1 with some exceptions that I can't figure out.</s>

**Edit:** I solved it using user Greg Martin advice but I can't mark it as if he solved my problem so I'll credit him here.

Comment: Hint: $\sin x$ acts like $x$ when $x$ is near $0$, and $\cos x$ acts like $\pi/2-x$ when $x$ is near $\pi/2$. More concretely, the inequalities $x/2 < \sin x < x$ hold for all $0 < x < \pi/2$, and similarly for $\cos x$ (which is just the reflection of $\sin x$ on this interval anyway); these inequalities will allow you to compare the behavior of the integrand to simpler functions that it sounds like you're more used to.

Comment: It converges whenever $\displaystyle \Re\left({a}\right) < 1$ and $\displaystyle \Re\left({b}\right) < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

The function $f$, defined as

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x}{\sin(x)}&,x\ne 0\\\\1&, x=0\end{cases}$$

is analytic on $[0,\pi,2]$.

Now, write $\frac{1}{(\sin(x))^a}=\left(\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\right)^a\,\frac1{x^a}$.

Similarly, $\cos(x)=\sin(\pi/2-x)$

Can you proceed?